# Break, continue and exit issue while using with loop PHP 5.6

Tags: php

Switch statement works but, I am trying to break out of the loop but not having much luck.

I tried break, break 1, break 2 and continue but its not working. I am using PHP 5.6. Echo works fine and the data is coming out of the DB just fine. The problem is its printing three times.

```
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN verify
    WHERE uname='$showuser'";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
        $userid= $row["id"];
        $verify= $row["verified"];

    //NB! Notice how the If and While Loop are not closed here

    ?>

    <?php echo " stuff etc etc" ?>

        <?php 
            //I cant seem to some out of the IF statement. I tried BREAK, CONTINUE and EXIT.
            switch ($verify) {
            case '1': echo "<img src='passed.png' />"; break 1;
            case '3': echo "<img src='failed.png' />"; break 1;

            default:  echo "<img src='waiting.png' />"; break;
            }//END switch
        ?>


        <?php }} //END first IF & WHILE loops

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE e.ctable_id = $userid ";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){  
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){  

        ?>

        <?php echo " stuff etc etc" ?>

        <?php } } //END second IF & WHILE loops ?>
```

Everything was fine before I added the switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, **while**, do-while or **switch** structure.

`break 1` will only break out of your "switch" statement, you will need `break 2` to reach the while loop nesting level.

```
$count = 0;
while( $count++ < 10 )
{
  echo 'while';
  switch( true )
  {
    case true:
      echo 'switch';
      break 2; // TWO is needed here to break out of TWO levels of nesting
  }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it **how many nested enclosing structures** are to be broken out of. **The default value is 1**, only the immediate enclosing structure is broken out of.

Answer (score 0):

To  stop the rest of the script from running you can  do

```
exit;
```

If you want to exit out of the if/else statement (if satisfied) do a

```
return;
```